# AS3 - AddEventlListener on Movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events

It's been a while since the last time I coded in AS3, so I cannot remember the right way to put a `Movieclip` inside the stage and then bind it to an event.
I did this:

1. Create an empty `MC` with an empty shape within and an empty keyframe with this AS3 code:

   `this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(){trace("ok");})`
2. Put the `MC` in the stage for the time I need it

*Unluckly, when I run it and I try to click, no message appears in the console.
Any idea?*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order for an object to dispatch a `CLICK` event, there must be something to click.  An empty shape has no bounds, and therefore nothing that can be clicked.  Filling/drawing something in the shape will resolve the problem.

```
this.graphics.beginFill(0);
this.graphics.drawRect(0,0, stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight);
this.graphics.endFill();
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(){trace("ok");})
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @papirtiger - If you looked you'd see this answer is from the author, and it is an answer to the question (be it a very poor one)

Comment: I may have been a bit quick on the close vote - but it was kind of hard to distinguish from a comment as it was originally written.

Answer (score 0):

In other way, Timeline clips always have the reference to the stage, so If you add listener to the `stage` instead of `this` you could trace `ok`.

Comment: Actually I don't think that will work.  There has to be something on the stage that will actually dispatch a click event first.  An empty stage will not dispatch a click event when you click it.

Comment: It should work.
stage represents main drawing area and it has displayObjectContainer , intereactive object ...  as ancestors. It is not globally accessible, but when come to stage it should work.

Comment: Yes, but only if it has a child on it that can actually dispatch a click event, which doesn't seem to be the case in the question.   Create an empty flash project,  add a click listener to stage, run the project then click the background of the stage when you run, your listener likely won't be called.

Comment: Though I just tried in Flash Develop and it worked, so maybe I'm completely wrong...